# 32bit vs 64bit drivers

Tags: c, windows, 32bit-64bit, device-driver

are there any specifics when developing a device driver (kernel-mode) on Windows 7 32 bit or Windows 7 64 bit? Can I develop on some platform and prepare builds to run on the other one?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428). Yes, you should be able to cross-compile.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But are there any API specifics for 64 bit platform? E.g. using other data-types or something...

Answer (score 1):

That's what MSDN is for:  64-bit System Design

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg566940

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do anything funny, producing a 64-bit driver shouldn't require any changes except for a rebuild.

Comment: The question is about explaining what are those "funny" methods, for example stuffing pointers into integers is quite popular and is certainly not compatible with 32-bit integers.

Comment: I can't imagine stuffing pointers into integers happening a lot. Why would you do that in your own code? The APIs might have stuff akin to passing a pointer to a LPARAM/WPARAM (don't recall something like that offhand in the DDK, so I'm giving a usermode example) but in those cases, you trust Microsoft to define LPARAM in a safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_//feature/fprogramming/a-collection-of-examples-of-64-bit-errors-in-real-programs-r2767) are some possible source code bugs, which could arise while going from 32-bit to 64bit versions.